# "must have a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core" but I have one

Tags: firebase, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to update cordova plugins, and I'm getting this warning:

```
The app gradle file must have a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended.
```

It appears just as a warning. (Due to an unrelated problem, I unfortunately cannot test if the app works fine or not.)

The thing is, I do have a dependency on it;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
    }
}

// ...

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:27.+"
    compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

// ...

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What could cause this warning?

Comment: When u do cordova build android, what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: You are using a very old version of firebase-core compared to the Play services plugin.  Try updating to the latest versions. https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: @PeterHaddad I build with meteor, and the build goes okay, but afterwards I have to make some changes in Android Studio and then these problems happen when generating the APK.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. I tried it, and it makes no difference. (I see now that the app crash is not related to the warning, so it's not a big deal, though still strange.)